# Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' after UPDATE

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I got error Duplicate entry '53244' for key 'PRIMARY' after UPDATE

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE "
+ "tRN "
+ "SET RNDatumZ = NOW(), "
+ "yRNO = 0 "
+ "WHERE tRN.RNID = @RNID;",
                                                            konekcija.getConn()); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RNID", RNID);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When i do this on another server it works.
This is server where it is not working:
Server version: 10.4.11
Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.4.1
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.1
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
PHP version: 7.4.1
Version information: 4.9.2, latest stable version: 5.2.0

And this is server where it works:
Server version: 10.4.11
Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.4.2
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.2
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation curl Documentation mbstring Documentation
PHP version: 7.4.2
Version information: 5.0.1, latest stable version: 5.2.0

This is table i want to update
https://i.stack.imgur.com/la4ux.png

Comment: That seems pretty self-explanatory, does it not?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the forum. Please don't post images as the links tend to die over time. Without any code to check I would surmise that you are attempting to write a record with a conflicting primary index value. An update shouldn't change the primary key.

Comment: Nope, why i get this error when i wanna update column?

Comment: I dont update primary key.

Comment: Well, provide a [mcve] and we can help you. What are we supposed to do with an SQL query and an error? We don't know your database table, columns, constraints, etc. Also, you're supposed to provide code as formatted _text_ in your question, not as an image.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please have a [tour] and learn [ask]. without the knowledge which column is configured as **primary key**, we can't quite provide you more advice. also, please post the error message as text, some internet provider where i live disallow access to imgur :(

Comment: Also error may be from a trigger..

Comment: `yRNO` appears to have a key icon next to it (foreign key, I assume)? Presumably you're setting it to 0, but no entry exists in the foreign table corresponding to that id.

Comment: It is from trigger

Answer (score 0):

check if you have unique constraint on column yRNO and you may already have 0 value in this column. If its not the case, run the query directly in database to see the exact error, It seems not related to code but query.